# Reemplazar valores array asociativo

Tags: php

Tengo dos arrays asociativos, uno así:

```
[
  {
    "email": "<string>",
    "first_name": "<string>",
    "last_name": "<string>",
    "id": 17051153,
  },
  {
    "email": "<string>",
    "first_name": "<string>",
    "last_name": "<string>",
    "id": 91653139,
  }
]
```

El otro así:

```
[
  {
    "id": 73631797,
    "day": -28676141,
    "month": 65614392,
    "year": 88904725,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 17051153,
    "observations": "<string>"
  },
  {
    "id": -89785905,
    "day": 44398558,
    "month": -79516608,
    "year": -31861537,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 91653139,
    "observations": "<string>"
  }
]
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar los datos del segundo array sustituyendo el "employee_id" por el "first_name" del primer array, los arrays estarían vinculados del primer array "id" con "employee_id" del segundo array.

He probado con array_merge() y array_map() pero no lo estoy haciendo nada bien

```
$results = array();
$results[] = $obj;
$results[] = $obj_employees;
$mapeo = function($elemento) {
    return array(
        'id' => $elemento['id'],
        'nombre' => $elemento['full_name']
        );
}
return array_map($mapeo, $results);
```

Este ejemplo me devuelve error 500

Comment: Por qué pone $obj y entonces $obj_employees en $results?  Y con error 500 debe ser un entrada en el error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta combinación de bucle `foreach`, con `array_search` y `array_map` tambien funcionaría:

```php
<?php
$empleados = '[
 {
  "email": "@uno",
  "first_name": "pedro",
  "last_name": "<string>",
  "id": 17051153
 },
 {
  "email": "@dos",
  "first_name": "juan",
  "last_name": "<string>",
  "id": 91653139
  }
 ]';

$fichas = '[
  {
    "id": 73631797,
    "day": -28676141,
    "month": 65614392,
    "year": 88904725,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 17051153,
    "observations": "<string>"
   },
   {
    "id": -89785905,
    "day": 44398558,
    "month": -79516608,
    "year": -31861537,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 91653139,
    "observations": "<string>"
   }
  ]';

$empleados = json_decode($empleados);
$fichas = json_decode($fichas);

foreach ($fichas as &$obj) {
    $obj->employee_id = $empleados[
        array_search(
            $obj->employee_id,
            array_map(function ($v) {
                return $v->id;
            },
            $empleados)
        )
    ]->first_name;
}

print_r($fichas);
```

**Explicación línea por línea:**

Tal como ha realizado @Danny en su respuesta, lo primero es decodificar los strings **json** mediante [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), que en este caso se transforman en **array** donde cada uno de los elementos contenidos es un *objeto* con sus propiedades.

```php
$empleados = json_decode($empleados);
$fichas = json_decode($fichas);
```

**Nota:** Los he llamado así porque en uno me ha parecido que eran datos de empleados (`$empleados`), y el otro fichas de registro de sus actividades (`$fichas`).

El paso siguiente es recorrer el *array* `$fichas` mediante la función [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) y pasando cada *objeto [por referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php)* mediante el uso de `&` delante de la nueva variable denominada, en este caso, `$obj`. De este modo:

```php
foreach ($fichas as &$obj) {
```

Ya dentro del bucle asignamos (`=`), en cada iteración, a la propiedad `emploee_id` del *objeto* (`$obj`) el valor de la propiedad `first_name` del *array* `$empleados`, solo cuando la propiedad actual `employee_id` de `$fichas` coincide con la propiedad actual `id` de `$empleados`.

```php
$obj->employee_id = $empleados[
        array_search(
            $obj->employee_id,
            array_map(function ($v) {
                return $v->id;
            },
            $empleados)
        )
    ]->first_name;
```

Analicemos esta instrucción con detalle. A modo de esquema, lo que hace es esto:

```php
$obj->employee_id = $empleados[x]->first_name;
```

donde **x** sería el resultado de la función `array_seach` que usamos para buscar **la primera coincidencia** de `$obj->employee_id` actual de `$fichas` con la propiedad `id` de los *objetos* contenidos en el *array* `$empleados`.

Es decir, `x` representa esto:

```php
array_search(
    $obj->employee_id,
    array_map(function ($v) {
        return $v->id;
    },
    $empleados)
)
```

[array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) **sólo devuelve la clave de la primera coincidencia**, evitando tener que recorrer todo el **array a buscar** cada vez. *Recordemos esto de **la clave** para cuando apliquemos el `array_map`*.

*Se busca el valor de su primer parámetro*, que en este caso es **`$obj->employee_id`**, en el *array a búscar*, que en este caso esta representado por el retorno de la función `array_map`, de este modo:

```php
array_map(function ($v) {
    return $v->id;
},
$empleados)
```

[`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) nos va a devolver un array que contiene todos los elementos del array `$empleados` **después** de aplicarle la función de retrollamada (callback) que aparece en su primer parámetro, en este caso esta:

```php
function ($v) {
    return $v->id;
}
```

que si nos fijamos y aprendemos a interpretarla, el parámetro `$v` de esa función representa *un elemento del array* `$empleados`, es decir, en este caso un *objeto completo con todas sus propiedades*, **que varia en cada iteración de map** (no se si deben llamarse así, es para que se me entienda), y del cual tan solo queremos saber su `id`, y por eso hacemos el `return $v->id`.  De esta forma, cuando termina el `array_map`, nos habra generado un array con los `id` y con las mismas claves que el array `$empleados`.

Como he dicho antes, `array_search` va a devovlernos esa **clave** del retorno de `array_map` que coincide con el valor de `$obj->employee_id`. Es decir, la `x` que antes he mencionado, y por lo tanto, va a proceder con la asignación correctamente, que era:

```php
$obj->employee_id = $empleados[x]->first_name;
```

Y asi en cada iteración de los elementos de tipo *objeto* de $fichas, sustituyendo esa propiedad por el `first_name` correspondiente, tal como se habia preguntado.

Finalmente mostramos el resultado de todos los cambios, ya fuera del bucle, mediante:

```php
print_r($fichas);
```

donde estas propiedades habran quedado así:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 73631797
            [day] => -28676141
            [month] => 65614392
            [year] => 88904725
            [clock_in] => <string>
            [clock_out] => <string>
            [employee_id] => pedro
            [observations] => <string>
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => -89785905
            [day] => 44398558
            [month] => -79516608
            [year] => -31861537
            [clock_in] => <string>
            [clock_out] => <string>
            [employee_id] => juan
            [observations] => <string>
        )

)
```

Comment: Utilicé tu solución, adaptando un poco el código, muchas gracias por la explicación me ha servido para entenderlo perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, esa era la idea. Entiendo que tu adaptación del código quizás mejoraba mi sistema para hacerlo y si es así estaria bien que la compartieras con la comunidad tambien en forma de nueva respuesta (puedes responderte a ti mismo si quieres).

Comment: No no, no cambia la base ni la ejecución simplemente modifiqué un poco para obtener otros resultados. Tu respuesta es la perfecta.

Comment: Vale, entendido, pues lo dicho, me alegro que te haya ido bien. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Espero y esto pueda solucionar tu problema

```
<?php

$datos1= '[
 {
  "email": "@uno",
  "first_name": "pedro",
  "last_name": "<string>",
  "id": 17051153
 },
 {
  "email": "@dos",
  "first_name": "juan",
  "last_name": "<string>",
  "id": 91653139
  }
 ]';

 $datos2 = '[
  {
    "id": 73631797,
    "day": -28676141,
    "month": 65614392,
    "year": 88904725,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 17051153,
    "observations": "<string>"
   },
   {
    "id": -89785905,
    "day": 44398558,
    "month": -79516608,
    "year": -31861537,
    "clock_in": "<string>",
    "clock_out": "<string>",
    "employee_id": 91653139,
    "observations": "<string>"
   }
  ]';

  $lista1 = json_decode($datos1);
  $lista2 = json_decode($datos2);
  $temp = array();

  foreach($lista1 as &$fila) {
     array_push($temp,$fila->first_name);
  } 

  foreach($lista2 as $key=>$fila) {
    $fila->employee_id=$temp[$key];
  }    

  print_r($lista2);
 ?>
```